# When to use the <script> tag in the head and body section of a html page?

Tags: javascript, html

When we have to use `<script>` tag inside `<head>` section and when we have to use the `<script>` tag inside `<body>` section? What is the difference between these two occurrences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106462/whats-the-difference-between-putting-script-in-head-and-body

Comment: please refer the following link with detailed explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Answer (score 54):

Scripts in `<head>`

> Scripts to be executed when they are called, or when an event is
>   triggered, are placed in functions.
>
> Put your functions in the head section, this way they are all in one
>   place, and they do not interfere with page content.

Scripts in `<body>`

> If your is not placed inside a function, or if your script writes page
>   content, it should be placed in the body section.  It is a good idea
>   to place scripts at the bottom of the `<body>` element. This can
>   improve page load, because script compilation can slow down the
>   display.

In short and simple language:

1. Place library script such as the jQuery library in the head section.
2. Place normal script in the head unless it becomes a performance/page
   load issue.
3. Place script that impacts the render of the page at the end of
   the body

Comment: If your ..  under "Scripts in <body>" section means?

Answer (score 19):

`<script>` tags are loaded and executed by the browser as and when it encounters them. Most modern browsers have a number of multiple threads that render the HTML page at the same time, however, if all those threads are blocked waiting to load JavaScript assets, the page takes a whole lot longer to render.

That's the reason people usually place their `<script>` tags in the `<body>` at the bottom of the page, so that all the HTML of the page has been rendered, and the user can see something while the page loads any heavy JavaScript assets.