# Why does my code not log each button of the calculator elements?

Tags: javascript, loops, calculator

The code below is intended to loop through each button and log it to the console.
I'm ultimatelty trying to create a calculator, but first I have to be able to get
identity of each button, however, I can't seem to understand why my code is not working
as intended. Any answer would greatly be appreciated, thank you.

````
 <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
        <script src="calculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Calculator Design Using HTML Layout</h1>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="header">Calculator</div>
              <input type="text" class="result">
              <div class="first-row">
                <input type="button" name="" value="&radic;" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="(" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value=")" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="%" class="global">
              </div>
              <div class="second-row">
                <input type="button" name="" value="7" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="8" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="9" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="/" class="global">
              </div>
              <div class="third-row">
                <input type="button" name="" value="4" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="5" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="6" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="X" class="global">
              </div>
              <div class="fourth-row">
                <input type="button" name="" value="1" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="2" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="3" class="global">
                <input type="button" name="" value="-" class="global">
              </div>
              <div class="conflict">
                <div class="left">
                  <input type="button" name="" value="0" class=" big">
                  <input type="button" name="" value="." class=" small">
                  <input type="button" name="" value="Del" class=" red small white-text top-margin">
                  <input type="button" name="" value="=" class=" green white-text big top-margin">
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                  <input type="button" name="" value="+" class="global grey plus">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
      </body>
    </html>
    
    ```
    let numbers =  document.getElementsByClassName("global")
    for(let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
      console.log(numbers[i])
    }

```
````

Comment: where is your script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this answer on a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407984/10521934) regarding the position of script tags.

Due to the script being run from the head of the document, the rest of the page is not available when it runs the query, and as such, it will return either nothing (i.e. a bunch of `undefined`) or an error.

Place the script tag at the bottom of your document's `body` to avoid this error.