# Code only works in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with some code.
It only runs in jsfiddle and i dont know why it's not working in codepen or in files.

Why does this code only works in jsfiddle?
I tried it in codepen and just in files but it doesnt show anything
http://jsfiddle.net/auagufL8/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all.js">   </script>

<div id="container"></div>


$(function () {

// Prepare demo data
var data = [
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-fr",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-gr",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-fl",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ze",
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-nh",
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-zh",
        "value": 5
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-dr",
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ge",
        "value": 7
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-li",
        "value": 8
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ov",
        "value": 9
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-nb",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ut",
        "value": 11
    }
];

// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {

    title : {
        text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle : {
        text : 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all.js">The Netherlands</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series : [{
        data : data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/nl/nl-all'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
 });


#container {
height: 500px; 
min-width: 310px; 
max-width: 800px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
margin-top: 10em;
text-align: center;
color: gray;
}
```

Comment: I added the code in a js file

Comment: and link them in the html file

Comment: [**Say what!**](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/60ff082e42d3ac685db69b2ef82359af) - You probably didn't add the JS files or include jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oh!**

This code perfectly works everywhere.
To get it to work in Codepen, you need to add all your JS resources via the little cog **inside JS panel**, and check that `Latest version of jQuery` is selected. `<script>` tags are ignored in HTML panel.

```js
$(function () {

    // Prepare demo data
    var data = [
        {"hc-key": "nl-fr","value": 0},
        {"hc-key": "nl-gr","value": 1},
        {"hc-key": "nl-fl","value": 2},
        {"hc-key": "nl-ze","value": 3},
        {"hc-key": "nl-nh","value": 4},
        {"hc-key": "nl-zh","value": 5},
        {"hc-key": "nl-dr","value": 6},
        {"hc-key": "nl-ge","value": 7},
        {"hc-key": "nl-li","value": 8},
        {"hc-key": "nl-ov","value": 9},
        {"hc-key": "nl-nb","value": 10},
        {"hc-key": "nl-ut","value": 11}
    ];

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        title : {
            text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
        },
        subtitle : {
            text : 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all.js">The Netherlands</a>'
        },
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/nl/nl-all'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            name: 'Random data',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 500px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run code is a browser, you need to put it inside a `<script> //Your code goes here </script>` tag

Comment: And he needs to put the CSS rules in a `<style>...</style>`tag

Answer (score 0):

this ->

```
#container {
    height: 500px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .loading {
    margin-top: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
    }
```

Is CSS, it must be inside a `<style>` tag.

this ->

```
$(function () {

// Prepare demo data
var data = [
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-fr",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-gr",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-fl",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ze",
        "value": 3
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-nh",
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-zh",
        "value": 5
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-dr",
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ge",
        "value": 7
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-li",
        "value": 8
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ov",
        "value": 9
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-nb",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "hc-key": "nl-ut",
        "value": 11
    }
];

// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {

    title : {
        text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle : {
        text : 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all.js">The Netherlands</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series : [{
        data : data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/nl/nl-all'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
 });
```

Is Javascript, it must be inside a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your CSS related files either in a separate .css file or put it under  tag in your HTML file. Also put all the scripts inside a .js file or embed it under  tag in your HTML file.

for more reference you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625773/where-should-i-put-the-css-and-javascript-code-in-an-html-webpage) older post.