# How to hide the home swipe bar in Safari for iOS?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Is there a way using css/html/js to hide the home swipe bar in Safari for iOS?

[image: home bar]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide Safari Mobile browser bottom button bar in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191240/how-to-hide-safari-mobile-browser-bottom-button-bar-in-iphone)

Comment: No, this is a completely different topic

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144762/i-want-to-hide-a-div-when-people-will-open-in-safari-and-in-place-of-that-it-wil

Comment: This is not possible because it is done by the phone itself and it is there to return to the home screen. So no, it is not possible