# I cannot succes to make my input text accept only links from a specific website

Tags: php, html, input, hyperlink, insert

So what i'm trying to do is to make this input accept only links like as example from mega.nz and if it's recivies any other links from any other website it would refuse and says a message on the top of the page *Use Mega.nz* and thanks so much for helping

```
<p>
    <label for="firstName">Link:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Link" placeholder="only mega.nz links"> 
</p>
```

Comment: formatting improved

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple validation, like this:

```js
$("#Link").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
  var url = $(this).val();
  isValid = url.includes("mega.nz");
  if(isValid) {
    $(this).prev("label").removeClass("error");
  } else {
    $(this).prev("label").addClass("error");
  }
});
```

```css
label.error {
  color:#ff0000;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="Link">Link:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Link" name="Link" placeholder="only mega.nz links" />
</p>
```

Comment: excuse me what's #Link

Comment: I'm pretty confused where do i put exactly the script ?

Comment: You must wrap up the javascript code in <script> tag, CSS styles in <style> tag and put it all together in your <head>. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625773/where-should-i-put-the-css-and-javascript-code-in-an-html-webpage)