# How to link html css and js together

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

I'm working on a small website project using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. So I followed the tutorial, but now that I have a .html file, a .css file and a .js file I don't know how to make them work together. Sorry for the silly question, but I really need to know how to link the .css file and the .js file in the .html file. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I put the CSS and Javascript code in an HTML webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625773/where-should-i-put-the-css-and-javascript-code-in-an-html-webpage)

Answer (score 5):

To link CSS - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

To link JS - `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Your HTML document would look like this -

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Title of your HTML page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Put your HTML here  -->

    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

To import css files on html use tag link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> // file.css
```

To import js files use tag script

```
<script src="file.js"></script>  // file.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want to put your CSS (stylesheet) in you `<head>` tag.

For example:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_css.css" />
</head>
```

Speaking of scripts, nowadays I think browsers load JavaScript in parallel, so it doesn't make a big difference, but from what I've learned in the past - putting javascript just before the end of the `<body>` tag is a good practice.

```
<body>
  ... your HTML content here
  ...
  <script src="path_to_js.js" />
</body>
```